# How can i show progress of a loop in python script that runs on clicking a button?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm using ajax to run a python script on clicking a button, and I want to display progress of a loop in that python script. How can I achieve that?
At present what my program does is that it alerts me when python script is finished.I want to show the progress meter on the same page meanwhile the script is running.

Comment: Check out `tqdm` module in python

Comment: How would tqdm help the OP to achieve progress bar in web app (see django) tag?

Answer (score 0):

If a loading bar is what you are trying to make, you could put code at set points on the loop to give you a value on the progress. Example: Halfway into the loop you can put code that sets a variable = 50 and display that variable every time you reach a given point. every 5 lines of code ect...

Comment: Venom Thanks for ur response but I want to know how i can i display that on that page simultaneously as the script is running

Comment: I think the OP is looking for web app counter.. see django tag in question.